# Push project to Git not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, commit

I really need to upload a project to GitHub to Eclipse in the next five minutes.
I right click on the project and go to "Team", but none of the options are "Commit".

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: If it's really urgent I would just download the native client https://windows.github.com/

Comment: I have, but I can't find how to use it...

Comment: have you pulled the existing project?

Comment: Yes, But I still can't find how to commit. I have the README.md.

Comment: you have to add your java (?) files into that project folder, the github client will detect the changes and then you can commit and sync everything

Comment: How do I add the Java files into the project folder?

Comment: its a real folder on your pc. so just copy the java files and paste them into it. (obviously it would be much better in the future to make the project folder your workspace in eclipse)

Comment: I don't understand where to move them into. They're on my desktop... now where should they be?

Comment: in the same folder as `readme.md`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have createda gitHub repository and installed git on your computer, you have to start the command prompt in your project directory in eclipse workspace and type:

```
$ git init
```

Then you'll need to get the correct URL for your repository on GitHub and type:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/[username]/[reponame].git
```

Now, add all files to your local commit:

```
$ git add .   # this adds all the files
```

Then make an initial commit:

```
$ git commit -a -m "Initial commit"
```

Finally, to put it on the remote, do:

```
$ git push -u origin --all
```